# Doing a pandas left merge with duplicate column names (want to delete left and keep right)

Tags: python, pandas, join, merge

So let's say I have df_1

```
       Day         Month       Amt              
 --------------- --------- ---------  
  Monday            Jan      10              
  Tuesday           Feb      20 
  Wednesday         Feb      30
  Thursday          April    40
  Friday            April    50
```

and df_2

```
       Month        Amt              
 --------------- ---------
      Jan          999
      Feb          1000000
      April        123456
```

I want to get the following result when I do a left merge:

```
       Day         Month       Amt              
 --------------- --------- ---------  
  Monday            Jan      999              
  Tuesday           Feb      1000000 
  Wednesday         Feb      1000000
  Thursday          April    123456
  Friday            April    123456
```

So basically the 'Amt' values from the right table replace the 'Amt' values from the left table where applicable.

When I try

```
df_1.merge(df_2,how = 'left',on = 'Month')
```

I get:

```
       Day         Month       Amt_X   Amt_Y              
 --------------- --------- ---------  -------
  Monday            Jan      10        999       
  Tuesday           Feb      20        1000000
  Wednesday         Feb      30        1000000
  Thursday          April    40        123456
  Friday            April    50        123456
```

Anyone know of a simple and efficient fix? Thanks!

Comment: you need a union or update statement not a left merge, it's detailed in the above post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This answer is purely supplemental to the duplicate target.  That is a much more comprehensive answer than this.

### Strategy #1

there are two components to this problem.

#### Use `df_2` to create a mapping.

The intuitive way to do this is

```
mapping = df_2.set_index('Month')['Amt']
```

which creates a series object that can be passed to `pd.Series.map`

However, I'm partial to

```
mapping = dict(zip(df_2.Month, df_2.Amt))
```

Or even more obtuse

```
mapping = dict(zip(*map(df_2.get, df_2)))
```

#### Use `pandas.Series.map`

```
df_1.Month.map(mapping)

0        999
1    1000000
2    1000000
3     123456
4     123456
Name: Month, dtype: int64
```

Finally, you want to put that into the existing dataframe.

#### Create a copy

```
df_1.assign(Amt=df_1.Month.map(mapping))

         Day  Month      Amt
0     Monday    Jan      999
1    Tuesday    Feb  1000000
2  Wednesday    Feb  1000000
3   Thursday  April   123456
4     Friday  April   123456
```

#### Overwrite existing data

```
df_1['Amt'] = df_1.Month.map(mapping)
```

---

### Strategy #2

To use `merge` most succinctly, drop the column that is to be replaced.

```
df_1.drop('Amt', axis=1).merge(df_2)

         Day  Month      Amt
0     Monday    Jan      999
1    Tuesday    Feb  1000000
2  Wednesday    Feb  1000000
3   Thursday  April   123456
4     Friday  April   123456
```